# How do you create an AWS Cloudfront Distribution that points to an S3 (static hosted) Website Endpoint using the SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-ruby

I have an S3 bucket configured as a website endpoint to host a static web page.

I want to put Cloudfront in front of it.

I copied the *"Endpoint"* from the S3 Bucket's *"Properties"* :: *"Static Website Hosting."*

It is of the form:  *"example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"*

When I try to create_distribution using the Aws SDK CloudFront Client I get this Error:

```
Aws::CloudFront::Errors::InvalidArgument 
The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.
```

Example Ruby Code is as follows:

```
cloudfront = Aws::CloudFront::Client.new()
cloudfront.create_distribution({
  distribution_config: {
    ...
    origins: {
      quantity: 1,
      items: [{
        id: "Custom-example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        domain_name: "example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        s3_origin_config: {
          origin_access_identity: ""
        },
        origin_path: ""
      }]
    },
    ...
  }
```

})

I am able to create a distribution with the same "Origin Domain Name" through the GUI as well as through the CLI

```
aws cloudfront create-distribution \
  --origin-domain-name example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com \
  --default-root-object index.html
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Websites Endpoints that are statically hosted on an S3 bucket need to be configured as an "Origin Type" *"custom_origin"* and *NOT* S3_Origin.  You can see that this is the case under the "Origins" Tab for the Distribution in the GUI.

Sample Ruby Code:

```
    distribution_config: {
    ...
      origins: {
        quantity: 1,
        items: [{
          id: "Custom-example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          domain_name: "example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          custom_origin_config: {
            http_port: 80, # required
            https_port: 443, # required
            origin_protocol_policy: "http-only", # required, accepts http-only, match-viewer, https-only
          },
        }]
     ...
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - this was pretty much impossible to find out...